# How to find all the construct methods on the fly after importing ttk module into Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ide, ttk

How to find all the construct methods on the fly in ttk module being called in Python. As the documentation is overwhelming want to know the command/statement to see the list dynamically while coding. If I wish to use button() -> Checkbutton() -> set() & get() and so on

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you want. You can get a list of the methods common to all ttk wigets [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Widget.html) and the list of options and methods specific to the `ttk.Checkbutton` [here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Checkbutton.html). Otherwise most IDE provide some autocompletion which can help you get the method and class names on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was looking at this in a way either it can be command prompt help with each of the methods for all ttk widgets while coding or code snippets for which I got "Tkinter Snippets" in VS code which is having a list of snippets. As Im new to ttk want to know easier way to get pointer while coding which is slightly getting tricky to go and refer to documentation every time. Thanks again.